# Error saving formula - IF statement needs revision

Tags: visualforce, if

I need to simplify my code, due to the IF formula being too long.  This formula is being used in a visualforce page that populates a pagesection based on user input choices.

Can someone help me with shortening this so I no longer get an error?

```
<apex:pageblockSection rendered="{!
    OR(
        AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom'), 
            !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'), 
            )
        AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night'),
            !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'), 
            )
        AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning'),
            !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'), 
            )
        AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c, 'Cooking Safety/Meal Prep'),
            !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'), 
            )
        AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night'),
            !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'), 
            )
        AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family'),
            !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'), 
            )
        AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)'),
            !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'), 
            )
        AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c, 'Entering or Exiting the Home/Answering the Door'),
                (OR(
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom'), 
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c, 'Cooking Safety/Meal Prep'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair'),
                    !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'),
                    )
                )
            )
            AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c, 'Wandering or Elopement/Running Way or Egress (Leaving the Home)'),
                (OR(
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom'), 
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c, 'Cooking Safety/Meal Prep'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair'),
                    !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'),
                    )
                )
            )
            AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c, 'Confusion or Dementia'),
                (OR(
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom'), 
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c, 'Cooking Safety/Meal Prep'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair'),
                    !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'),
                   )
                )
            )
            AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c, 'Accessing Help for an Emergency'),
                (OR(
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom'), 
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c, 'Cooking Safety/Meal Prep'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair'),
                    !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'),
                    )
                )
            )
            AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Walking or Mobility'),
                (OR(
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom'), 
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c, 'Cooking Safety/Meal Prep'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair'),
                    !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'),
                    )
                )
            )
            AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair'),
                (OR(
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom'), 
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c, 'Cooking Safety/Meal Prep'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c, 'Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)'),
                    CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair'),
                    !CONTAINS(Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c, 'Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'),
                   )
                )
            )

        )
}">
                    <apex:outputText value="SH System Recommendation"/>
              </apex:pageblockSection>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be using a formula for this. Build a method in Apex and use the result from that instead:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!shouldShowSection}">
```

Which is then a getter method:

```
public Boolean getShouldShowSection() {
  if(record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom' && !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)')) {
    return true;
  }
  if(record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') && !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)'))  {
    return true;
  }
  // more if statements here as needed
  // Finally, we return false if the above if statements were not met:
  return false;
}
```

I suspect it may be possible optimize your conditions further, too, you may want to take more time optimizing your logic.